# How to add a polygon I can move with manipulate to a graph?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, polygons

I am trying to add a polygon that I can move around with manipulate to a graph.  The polygon would have four points, each of which can be moved around with a locator.

This is the code I have:

```
Manipulate[Module[{fem, male, countries, pol},
  
  countries = CountryData["Countries"];
  fem = Map[CountryData[#, "FemaleLifeExpectancy"] &, countries];
  male = Map[CountryData[#, "MaleLifeExpectancy"] &, countries];
  
  pol = Polygon[{{p1}, {p2}, {p3}, {p4}}];
  
  
  Show[
   ListPlot[Transpose[{fem, male}],
    AxesLabel -> {"Female Life Expectancy", "Male Life Expectancy"}],
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Dashed,Red}], White, pol}]
   
   ]],
 {{p1, {50, 60}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {50, 70}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {60, 70}}, Locator},
 {{p4, {60, 80}}, Locator}
 
 ]
```

Unfortunately, the polygon area is not showing up and the dashed line that marks the edges isn't either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{fem, male, countries, pol}
  , countries = CountryData["Countries"];
  fem = Map[CountryData[#, "FemaleLifeExpectancy"] &, countries];
  male = Map[CountryData[#, "MaleLifeExpectancy"] &, countries];
  reg = BoundingRegion[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, "MinOrientedRectangle"];
  ListPlot[Transpose[{fem, male}]
   , Frame -> True
   , FrameLabel -> {"Female Life Expectancy", "Male Life Expectancy"}
   , Prolog -> {
     EdgeForm[{Dashed, Red}]
     , FaceForm[Yellow]
     , reg
     , Text[
      Style["Area = " <> ToString@RegionMeasure[reg], Red, Bold], {80,
        50}]
     }
   ]
  ]
 ,
 {{p1, {60, 60}}, Locator}
 , {{p2, {60, 50}}, Locator}
 , {{p3, {80, 80}}, Locator}
 , {{p4, {80, 60}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response!

Comment: Please add the `AspectRatio -> Automatic` for a fair (visual) comparison (since it is ages and the axes should be 1:1. Also there are other options available with the `BoundingRegion`. My choice of the "form" is arbitrary.

Comment: Yeah, I just used Polygon and that worked best for what I wanted.